# Unity: (Using cardboard SDK) Can we download new images to set as skybox

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

We are creating a panoramic cardboard app.  We want administrators to pick the photos on a server.  How do we download those images on our device, and then set that in the skybox?

I am new to unity, but I do have audio clips being downloaded with WWW and I do have the skybox changing based on taps with resources that are bundled.  I am not understanding images well enough to understand how to download and then apply to the skybox.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question but you might have some success asking in http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unity skyboxes are cube maps comprised of 6 textures (top,bottom and 4 sides). So you need 6 textures, you can download via WWW and you can assign each to the correct property of the cubemap.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Skybox.html

A common panoramic format of course though is the cylidrical image, which has the full 360x180 degrees in a single image.

The editor has a handy feature that you can convert a texture of a cylidrical image straight to a cubemap, and then assign that to a skybox. This is very handy when you have want to make a skybox that is built into your game:

[image]

However, that is editor only - you can not perform that at runtime. You could create them in Unity, export as an asset bundle, and download that via WWW - but that would be a lot of work every time you wanted to create a new panorama!

For your situation, you would be better to not use a skybox, and instead create a 3d sphere with the normals facing inwards. And simply download cylindrical images via WWW and assign to the material on the sphere.

Note: you need several thousand polygons to make it render cleanly.

Comment: I think I followed and got one image working http://phandroid.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/building-44-photo-sphere-2.jpeg.  This one just shows as blue.  https://tulane.edu/tsweb/upload/IMG_4732.JPG  Do you have a suggestion what could be wrong?

Comment: That second image is a whopping 7868 × 5276. That will download but fail to load into a single texture. The current GL texture size limit on phones is typically 4096x4096 - but if you want to support older devices then 2048x2048 is what you want.